# Switching an Image with JavaScript from Selector

Tags: javascript, image, wordpress

I have a script that should switch out an image based on a selection from an HTML dropdown box.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form>
<select onChange="changeMap(this.value);">
<option value="clIP">Century Link - IP</option>
<option value="clND">Century Link - National Data</option>
<option value="elDF">Earth Link - Data Fiber</option>
<option value="elDSL">Earth Link - DSL</option>
<option value="l3">Level 3</option>
<option value="ws">Windstream</option>
<option value="xoBB">XO - BB</option>
<option value="xoFVOIP">XO - Flex VOIP</option>
<option value="xoIP">XO - IP</option>
</select>
</form>

<img src="imageurl" id="map" />
```

And here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
var maps=new Array();

maps[0]="imageurl";
maps[1]="imageurl";
maps[2]="imageurl";
maps[3]="imageurl";
maps[4]="imageurl";
maps[5]="imageurl";
maps[6]="imageurl";
maps[7]="imageurl";
maps[8]="imageurl";

function changeMap(inobj) {

switch (inobj) {

case "clIP":
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[0];
    break;

case "clND":
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[1];
    break;

case "elDF":
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[2];
    break;

case "elDSL":
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[3];
    break;

case "l3":
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[4];
    break;

case "ws":
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[5];
    break;

case "xoBB":
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[6];
    break;

case "xoFOIP"
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[7];
    break;

case "xoIP"
    document.getElementByID("map").src=maps[8];
    break;

default:
    document.write('Please select a map from the menu.');
    break;
}
```

So I have some very basic HTML with a drop down menu from which the user selects a map. I use JavaScript to change the image src to the value of an array based on the value of the selector. To me this code looks fine, but is simply not functional. The menu does nothing on select. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have troubles with this - I did a simple test and in all browsers I have available (latest Chrome, FF and IE) work perfectly:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test 12010414</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function switchImg(){
    var nextImg = "http://sarahhorth.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_16/custom-sample/rotator/sample-4.jpg",
        testImg = document.getElementById("testimg");
    if(testImg){
        testImg.src = nextImg;
    }
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="testimg" src="http://whitenoisecd.org/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-1.jpg" onclick="switchImg()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then perhaps my issue lies with the selector feeding values to the script or with the cases? Your example functions a little differently than mine.

Comment: ... one note more: You can also to construct Image object in JavaScript so all images will be loaded in background (simply run such script after page is loaded).

Comment: only mistake I see is that you have "getElementByID" instead of "getElementById" but I thought that is only a typing error